# MVC Passing a Complex Object to the controller for saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a web page with MVC and Entity Framework.
I have an order with line items attached and want to return a complex object to the controller for processing.

I have now included all the code.

**My view**:

```
@model BCMManci.ViewModels.OrderCreateGroup

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>New Order</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Order.Customer.FullName)</h4>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Order Date:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Order.OrderDate)</td>
            <td><b>Status:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Order.OrderStatus.OrderStatusName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <b>Notes</b>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Discount</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var product in Model.ProductWithPrices)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.ProductName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.SellingPrice)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.DiscountPrice)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.TotalPrice)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => product.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
<div class="btn btn-danger">
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Order,ProductWithPrices,Order.Note,product.Quantity")] OrderCreateGroup order)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Orders.Add(order.Order);

                foreach (var orderItem in order.ProductWithPrices.Select(item => new OrderItem
                {
                    OrderId = order.Order.OrderId,
                    ProductId = item.ProductId,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity,
                    ItemPrice = item.SellingPrice,
                    ItemDiscount = item.DiscountPrice,
                    ItemTotal = item.TotalPrice
                }))
                {
                    db.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ConfirmOrder", new {id = order.Order.OrderId});
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //TODO: Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        ViewBag.Products = db.Products.Where(model => model.IsActive == true);

        PopulateDropdownLists();
        return View(order);
    }
```

**Data Source**:

```
public class OrderCreateGroup
{
    public OrderCreateGroup()
    {
        ProductWithPrices = new List<ProductWithPrice>();
    }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductWithPrice> ProductWithPrices { get; set; }
}

public class ProductWithPrice : Product
{
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPrice { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

However, the values that are entered on the form are not being passed, through. So I can't access them in the controller. The 'productWithPrices' collection is null although there is Data in it on the web page.

I have tried making it asyc and also tried changing the ActionLink button like below but it didn't get to the controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Orders", new { orderCreateGoup = Model }, null)
```

This is the controller but it now doesn't make sense as the parameter passed in the datasource for the page.

```
public ActionResult Create(OrderCreateGroup orderCreateGoup)
```

Please, can you give me direction on the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please post all the code of the view.

Comment: That is because your not generating the form controls in your form correctly (but you have not bother to show your code!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OrderCreateGroup` class initialize the collection to an empty list.

```
public class OrderCreateGroup
{
    public OrderCreateGroup()
    {
       ProductWithPrices = new List<ProductWithPrice>();
    }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductWithPrice> ProductWithPrices { get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SellingPrice)` and similarly for other bound fields that are using DisplayFor if you want to post them back to the controller.

**Note:** For your benefit, try to have a look at the generated HTML code when your page is rendered in the browser and see what tags are generated inside the `<form>` tag with a name attribute.

Comment: Thank you. That sorted Product with prices not coming back null. However, they are still empty.

Comment: Hey @ColinGenricks the issue is that your prices are bound to view using DisplayFor. DisplayFor wont post values back to the controller. You need to have a @Html.HiddenFor() for each of the price properties you need to post back to the controller.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I added the Hidden fields and now the values are pulling through for the Order

Answer (score 0):

make sure you bind the appropriate property from the complex object, like the following:

```
@model  BCMManci.ViewModels.OrderCreateGroup

...
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">


        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderCreateGroup.Order.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderCreateGroup.Order.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Note**:model.OrderCreateGroup.Order.Quantity would be one the your order's property.
hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried to implement your suggestion. However, as the datasource is OrderCreateGroup I was using: `model.Order.Notes` not `model.OrderCreateGroup.Order.Notes`. it is not allowing me to put this in. Does this mean my data source is set up incorrectly?